# How do I use the jQUERY Ajax to call the JSP in different port?no response when put in the diffrent directory

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jsonp, port

```
The html is on the
C:/xampp/htdocs/load/index.html
The jsp is on the
C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/jspmysql/load.jsp

the code in the index.html is as follow:
ajax({
type:"GET",//POST cannot work when the two files in the same tomcat directory.I donnot know why?      
dataType: 'jsonp',
//I chang this to "json" will work well when I put the two files in the same tomcat directiory and use the http://localhost:8080/index.html.But not the "jsonp".
//json and jsonp don't work and get the ajax error message.
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: {
Esites:123, 
Ssites:456 
},
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspmysql/load.jsp',
error: function(xhr) {
alert('Ajax request error');
},
success: function (response) {
alert("succeed");
alert("suceed="+response.msg);  // do stuff
},
complete: function () {
alert('After Send'); //this was fired
}
}); 
the load.jsp is as follows:
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String es = request.getParameter("Esites");
String ss = request.getParameter("Ssites");
out.println("{\"msg\": \"newsvgtemple.svg\",\"Esites\":\""+es+"\", \"Ssites\":\""+ss+"\"}");
%>
```

But when I run the index.html
I got the error function.
How do I fix the situation?Is it the cross-domain question? The different can be solve on the http://blog.yam.com/u9323523/article/25178591 php and jsp work together.Can I do the same thing on the xampp?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure that your java server is running on port 8080?  If so, then what you have here is correct for calling the JSP.

The 500 - Internal Server Error means that there was some error on the JSP page, not the port you're calling it on.  Try calling the JSP page without jQuery, in another browser window, and see what output you get.  If it is still a 500 error, then you have a coding problem in your JSP, not with your jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I try to put the two files in the same tomcat directory! It can work well when I change the "jsop" to "json".But when I put the two files in the different directory, such as above metioned.It will fire the error function(whenever the "json" or "jsonp". I cannot understand how to fix it.Can you give me another suggestion.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, I see your problem a bit more clearly now. I wasn't aware that you were trying to access them from across domains. The JSONP request should be taking care of that.  Can you put some debugging code into the .JSP page to log what's happening there, or is it simply not firing any code at all in that file?

Comment: I fix my jsp file at the last out.println.The XMLHttpRequest page is nothing on firebug when I put them in different directory(different port?80 and 8080);But when I use the json(not the jsonp) it works well in the same port 8080.I dont know how to explain my question and where to put the debug....As nothing happend just fire the error function "Ajax request error".